# Redirecting url to access subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress subdirectory install in a directory called 'wordpress'. So currently I am able to access the live site as follows: www.domain.com/wordpress.

My objective is for users to simply navigate to: www.domain.com, omitting the `wordpress` directory from the url.

I was wondering if someone can help me configure my `.htaccess` so every time a user navigates to anything with `domain.com/wordpress` it'll redirect to `domain.com`.

So for example: `domain.com/wordpress/admin` will become `domain.com/admin`

I created a new `.htaccess` file and placed in the root with the following contents, which did not work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite **/** to **/wordpress** you can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

This will internally redirect all requests from root to the subfolder.
Do not remove the **RewriteCond** directive otherwise the the rewrite destination will rewrite back to itself causing an infinite loop error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In which .htaccess should this code go? In the one within the wordpress directory, by appending it to the existing htaccess code, or are we adding this to a new htaccess file in the root level of the domain, which is one level up from the wordpress directory. I tried the latter without any success - It is redirecting incorrectly and ending up on dnssearch.com.

Comment: I suppose, since we're simply after performing some htaccess magic from the root of the domain, wouldn't it be possible to somehow omit the domain from the htaccess code altogether? so we're rewriting all traffic from `/` to `/wordpress`